# Is there some way to share variables between the two functions in hover() in jquery without using global variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, namespaces, global-variables

My code looks like this:

```
quickbarcolor = $("#quick-bar a").css("color");
$("#quick-bar a").hover(function () {
  if ($(this).css("color") != quickbarcolor) quickbarcolorhover = $(this).css("color");
 V$(this).animate({ color: quickbarcolorhover },400);
}, function() {
  $(this).animate({ 'color': quickbarcolor},400)}  
);
```

It works fine but it depends on global variables to share the colors between the two functions in hover(). I don't know everything about global vars but I thought it was better to avoid them unless necessary, though I know that sharing values between functions is what they are for. Still I'd like to see if anyone knows a better way of doing this.

Comment: Is your jQuery code inside a ready handler? If yes, you can create local variables in that handler.

Comment: yes obviously ... hadn't thought of that ... duh

Comment: A bit late to the party, but this is the way to do it, according to me -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/zHkxr/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to store your values on the DOM element being animated using the [`data-*`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) attribute. Here's what I mean by that:

```
$.data($("#quick-bar a"), "col", $("#quick-bar a").css("color"));

$("#quick-bar a").hover(function() {
    var self = $(this);
    var col = $.data(self, "col");
    if ($(this).css("color") != col) {
         $.data(self, "col", self.css("color"));
    }

    self.animate({
        color: col
    }, 400);

    $.data(self, "col", self.css("color");
}, function() {
    $(this).animate({
        'color':  $.data($(this), "col");
    }, 400)
});​
```

Comment: wow - never thought of that, good idea, how would it work, would I use attr() ?

Comment: Edited to provide an example (untested, but gives the basic idea).

Comment: I used copy/paste to whip something up quickly, editing to provide better code.

Comment: wouldn't you have to use each loop to since every 'a' could have a different color ?

Answer (score 4):

This approach creates no globals.

```
$(function() {
  var quickBar = $("#quick-bar a"),
      quickbarcolor = quickBar.css("color");

    quickBar.hover(function () {
        var $this = $(this), 
            color = $this.css("color");
        if ( color != quickbarcolor) {
             $this.animate({ color: color },400);
        }

    }, function() {
        $(this).animate({ 'color': quickbarcolor},400)}  
        );)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Or use JQuery data api.

```
$(this).data("myCustomData", "Hi");
```

Answer (score 0):

Data attributes are *not* a good thing since they are editable through any kind of html debugger like firebug. This could means anyone with it could change the behavior of your code (it's ok for a rollover, but think further...)

You could wait for the dom ready event to fire to add your code also, but you could *not* and then have a faster execution. So, *for me*, best way is to put your rollover declaration into an anonymouse function which will be in a script tag at the end of the html body tag. And if you're afraid of execution before jQuery has loaded, you could simply use defer attribute (compat' on [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=defer))

```
<html>
  <head>
    ...
    <script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" defer="defer"></script>
    ...
    </head>

  <body>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript" defer="defer">
      (function()
      {
        var strictly_private_var = 1;
        /* do your rollover */

      })();

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry ... maybe this is common knowledge but I cant find any info on it. I know it's possibly worthy of it's own question but could you elaborate `Data attributes are not a good thing since they are editable through any kind of html debugger like firebug. ` Do you mean edit the code on the server ... surely not ? ... that would make data attributes a major security liability wouldn't it ? ... Could you elaborate; or point me to a resource?

Comment: Do you know about firebug ? or maybe the chrome debugger ? Any people could use it and change the behavior of html/css/js of the page they currently browse. **Of course**, this won't be saved on the server. **Of course** the behaviors changed can be minors. But keep in mind that datasets (data-attributes) can be considered as global javascript variables since they are accessible freely with a simple document.getElementById("myId").getAttribute("data-myDataAttribute") and set the same way.

Comment: Yes have used firebug for a long time. I dont really understand though ... everything else is editable via firebug in this way too, but it's only local. I don't understand how this is bad ... or how data attributes are any different to anything else. Does the fact that they can be considered as global variables make it worse? I'm sure you are right but I dont understand exactly how it works. I will make a new question about this so you can provide a more detailed answer if you want.

Comment: Well it's maybe because i'm very paranoid :) but the fact is a dataset is editable by the javascript console and storing data that could be related to an ajax call to a server may be wrong. **I agree with you that in your case, it's not very relevant**. But it is important to me to mention that it's not always the best feature to use.